# Unable to create a functional executable with PyInstaller and PyQt

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have tried, for a lot of time now, to create an executable for a Python project. In this project, I need to use:

1. PyQt(4) : for my GUI,
2. PySerial : to communicate with an arduino,
3. Subprocess : to launch some avr things with a .bat file

In fact, the executable is created, but when I try to start it nothing happens, except my mouse tell me that she is occupied.

So, I tried to figured out from where could be the problem, by writing some basic programs, which condense every functions I need for my project. Everything is functional when I launch this from python (3.5), but doesn't when I execute the file generated by pyinstaller. (The interface.py file is [here, in a pastebin.com file](http://pastebin.com/CJNXH6sk), if you want, I thought it's not very relevant : it's only a form with a pushbutton)

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from interface import Ui_Form
import serial
import subprocess
import sys, os

class win(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    """docstring for win"""
    def __init__(self):
        super(win, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.ser = serial.Serial("COM3", 9600)
        self.pathBat = "cmd.bat"

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
            #if (self.ser.isOpen() and self.serAvr.isOpen()):
            if True:
                self.ser.write("start".encode())
                p = subprocess.call(self.pathBat, creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, **self.subprocess_args())

                if p == 1:
                    self.writeLog("Works")
                    self.ser.write("stop".encode())
                #self.writeLog(p.returncode)

    def subprocess_args(include_stdout=True):
        # The following is true only on Windows.
        if hasattr(subprocess, 'STARTUPINFO'):
            # On Windows, subprocess calls will pop up a command window by default
            # when run from Pyinstaller with the ``--noconsole`` option. Avoid this
            # distraction.
            si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
            si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
            # Windows doesn't search the path by default. Pass it an environment so
            # it will.
            env = os.environ
        else:
            si = None
            env = None


        ret = {}
        # On Windows, running this from the binary produced by Pyinstaller
        # with the ``--noconsole`` option requires redirecting everything
        # (stdin, stdout, stderr) to avoid an OSError exception
        # "[Error 6] the handle is invalid."
        ret.update({'stdin': subprocess.PIPE,
                    'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
                    'startupinfo': si,
                    'env': env })
        return ret


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
v = win()
v.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I added "cmd.bat" to the data in .spec file for pyinstaller, and the function *subprocess_arg* is here to avoid problems with subprocess (as mentionned on the documentation [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-subprocess))

Firstly I thought the problem was linked to subprocess, I tried to delete all the references to it, still not working. Same for Serial. Moreover, I tried to debug the executable by setting `debug = True` in the .spec file, but if I try to execute the file from the console, nothing happend at all, it stays blocked on the first line.

So if anybody can help ! thank you in advance !

Comment: Do you use `console=False`? This might be the reason you don't see anything on the command line. My best guess is that `interface` is the cause of the problem. Make sure that it is included in the build or create an example without it and try to "freeze" it.

Comment: I use `console=True` and `debug=True`. I just tried to add the `interface.py` to data to include in the spec file, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "frozen" application does not find the "cmd.bat"!? You could test it by replacing it with the absolute path.

Your executable unpacks the "cmd.bat" in a temporary folder accessible in python with `sys._MEIPASS`. You should find your files with something like `os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, "cmd.bat")` !?

In case you need it: `getattr(sys, 'frozen', False)` indicates whether your code is frozen or not (but only for PyInstaller).